# St. Angelo's fort tomb stone

Tags: india, tours, history, dutch-language

St. Angelo's fort, Kerala is one of the places that I'm panning to visit on my trip to south India. While researching, I happened to come across this picture of a tomb stone that was placed there in the 18th century. It has inscriptions on it, in what appears to be Dutch.

[image]

I'm just curious as to what it says. Would someone be able to translate it here?

Comment: Would somebody please translate it as it written out? I don't think the above comment is a word-to-word translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [asked here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dutch/comments/351qbv/can_someone_tell_me_whats_on_this_gravestone/) and got this answer:

```
Hieronder rusthen Lijk den

Here lies the body of

Egte Vrouwe Van de Heer

the wife of Mister

Godefridus Weijerman

Godefridus Weijerman

gen. Susanna Geertruijda

named Susanna Geertruijda

Pfeiffer in de kraam van eene

Pfeiffer while giving birth to a

Doode Soon Overleden

dead son [she] died

den 28 Maart Ao 1715[?] oud

on the 28 March 1715? [her] age

Sijnde 17 Jaren 7 Maanden

being 17 years, 7 months

en 16 Dagen

and 16 days

Aan Weersijde Van Deese

On the other side of this

Sarksteen Leggen Begra=

stone lie bur=
```

[Comment: A zarksteen or sarksteen was a way of referring to a natural stone.]

```
= ven twee kinderen van gem.

=ied two children of the same

Heer Weijerman geprocu=

Mr Weijerman obtain=

=reerd uijt de tweede [gt meet?]

=ed from the second [marriage with?]

de Vrouwe [Ioanna?] Anna

Mrs [Joanna] Anna

Banister het eerste kind

Banister the first child

gen. Godfried Wijnande

named Godfried Wijnande

Geb. den 28 Augo Ao 1749

Born on the 28 August in the year 1749

Gestorven den 2 [Zoer?] daar=

Died on the 2 [summer?]

=aan volgende Mitsgaders

following after that. Moreover

het Tweede Kind Genaamt

the second child named

Gotfred [Johan?] ontslapen

Gotfred Johan passed away

den 22 Julij Ao 1755 oud Wesen

on the 22 July in the year 1755 his age being

[de 13?] maanden en 8 dagen

[13?] months and 8 days
```